# How can I create a salary area chart with a specific data point

Tags: excel, charts, area-chart

I am trying to create a compensation breakdown for each employee to show their financial health in the market. I found instructions on here from 7 years ago for a column chart that was similar to what I'm looking for.

However, is there a way to have a specific point highlighted on an area chart?

I've attached the chart that I currently have, as you can see the data point is not in the blue section like I'd like it to be. I've tried all sorts of formatting and cannot get it to work. Help, please!?

Sample chart with data point here

[image]

Comment: Make a second series with the required value and all the other values as na(). Format as needed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to have a specific point highlighted on an area chart?

No, area charts are sums, or counts (like histograms) or actual values. So, when you want to combine that with raw data, it won't work as you requested.

[image]
*This only works if you have the same amount of data entries per data series. So, you need to have as many values for the blue area, as you have for the orange.*

Thus, this is will not work. Also, from my understanding, you want to show where "Andy"'s salary is in relation to others (and the max/min/average).

I wonder if you could do this some other way? Establish what you want to convey with this chart, maybe we can find some alternatives.

But to merge two different sized series, not possible as far as I am aware (not in a way that it looks good).

> I found instructions on here from 7 years ago for a column chart that was similar to what I'm looking for.

Would you mind sharing this? Maybe we can proceed further with that!